# Linear equations; how to write an equation from given coordinates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

A  straight line goes through the points $( 0, 1 )$, $( 2, 7 )$ and $( 4, 13 )$
and I need to write the equation of this straight line. How do you write equations?

I know you have it's usually $y = x \text{(something)} + \text{something}$.

Is it trial and error or is there a better way? We just got introduced to linear equations so it's new, I know how to work out the coordinates to make a line but I'm not sure on how to write the equation from coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

First, you only need *two* of those points. Let's take the first two, and make the identifications: $$(x_1,y_1) = (0,1)$$
$$ (x_2,y_2) = (2,7)$$

Then we use the slope formula: $$m = \dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

Finally, we plug all this into the "point slope" formula, and simplify as necessary: $$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$$

Comment: Comment deleted....

Comment: how do you plus it into the point slope? I'm a bit lost, so is it     0 - 2/ 1 - 7 = -2/-6 = -3?

Comment: Did you figure it out? The slope is $\dfrac{7-1}{2-0} = 3$...

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the gradient $m$ of the line by using two of the points given. Recall that gradient can be calculated by: $\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$
2. With a gradient and one point, you can use $y=mx+c$ by substituting the point into $x$ and $y$ to find the value of $c$, the y-intercept.
3. Lastly, take $y=mx+c$ and substitute $m$ and $c$ by the values you obtained in steps 1 and 2.

Check the points to see if all of them satisfy the equation of the line.

Comment: @HonkyHanka at which step are you stuck?

Comment: actually I got it, it's ok thanks